# How to insert an object in an array using Mongo shell commands?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have to insert an object `{"category" : "Vehicle"}` in the `rated` array below using Mongo shell commands. How can I do that?

```
 {
     "rating": {
         "userid": 1234,
         "bookingid": 4567,
         "rated": [
             {
                 "_id": "5aaa356f6b992b2068a1b691",
                 "category": "Driver",
                 "comment": "Good",
                 "rating": 5
             },
             {
                 "_id": "5aaa356f6b992b2068a1b690",
                 "category": "Overall",
                 "rating": 7
             }
         ]
     },
     "_id": "5aaa356f6b992b2068a1b68f",
     "__v": 0 }
```

Answer (score 4):

It's quite simple. Use `$push` method to push an object into an array.

```
db.ratings.update(
   { _id: ObjectId('5aaa356f6b992b2068a1b68f') },
   { $push: { rated: {"category" : "Vehicle"} } }
)
```

Here, `ratings` is the collection name.

This will insert an object into the rated array.

Comment: Please mark it right and do up if it is helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.update({
        "_id": ObjectId("5aaa356f6b992b2068a1b68f")
    }, {
        $addToSet: {
            'rating.rated': {
                "category": "Vehicle"
            }
        }
    }

)
```